# getting undefined on form submit reactjs

Tags: reactjs, forms, undefined

i'm building basic chat app with react, and i had many of SO form submit questions and answers but none are helped me, i know it may be dumb type question but really i'm stucked here, any helps are thank you, below is my code.

```
export default class Call extends Component {
 state = {
 Message:''
 };

 onChange = e => {
  let { Message, value } = e.target;
  console.log(e.target.value); // here i'm getting input value
  this.setState({ [Message]: value });
  };

onSubmit = e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log("Message is ", this.state.Message); //getting undefined
};  


render() {
 return (
   <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
    <input type="text" name="Message" onChange={this.onChange}/>
    <input type="submit" value="Send" />
   </form>
 )}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try without brackets:

```
onChange = e => {
  let { Message, value } = e.target;
  console.log(e.target.value); // here i'm getting input value
  this.setState({ Message: value });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize state inside class `constructor` and set it using `this.setState({ Message: value })` syntax.

```js
class Call extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
      Message: ''
    };
  }

  onChange = e => {
    let { value } = e.target;
    console.log(e.target.value); // here i'm getting input value
    this.setState({ Message: value });
  };

  onSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Message is ", this.state.Message); //getting undefined
  };

  render() {
    return ( 
      <form onSubmit={this.onSubmit}>
        <input type="text" name="Message" onChange={this.onChange} /> 
        <input type="submit" value="Send" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Call />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```